# How can I get Images in Yii framework?

Tags: database, image, yii

I have 100-120k addresses and I want all the images of these businesses and store in our database server in Yii framework. Is there any way I can automate this ? Because to do this manually It will take ages. ?

The data is something like this 
[image]

Comment: This seems extremely unclear. Where would the images be coming from?

Comment: You shoudl explain better .. I think is  possible  .. but depend  of the strcuture of your data ...

Comment: is there any way to get these images using google api

Comment: What images do you mean?

Comment: it could be a business logo or official  picture of a business.

Comment: This is not trivial to do and would require a major programming effort. How would you tell your program how to decide which of the many images on a page is the logo or official picture?